# Forcing code flow to go to except block

Tags: python

I have:

```
try:
   ...
except Exception, e:
   print "Problem. %s" % str(e)
```

However, somewhere in try, i will need it to behave as if it encountered an Exception. Is it un-pythonic to do:

```
try:
   ...
   raise Exception, 'Type 1 error'
   ...

except Exception, e:
   print "Problem. Type 2 error %s" % str(e)
```

Comment: it seems like bad design... but it is common to raise Exceptions ... but not typically this way... why do you need to do this? you may want to rethink what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Exception handling is generally designed for catching and handling _unintended_ failures. Exception _raising_ is for alerting consumers of your function of an error that prevented the functional block from completing, along with whatever information you wish to provide. If you just want to break out of a functional block as part of an intended behaviour, using a function and its return values would be a more appropriate way to handle that. That said, if you're trying to test the behaviour of the `except` block, then raising an exception in the `try` would be the way to do this.

Comment: But look at the last section of the python tutorial: 

docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this is a bad design.  If you need to take some action if (and only if) an exception wasn't raised, that is what the `else` clause is there for.  If you need to take some action unconditionally, that's what `finally` is for.  here's a demonstration:

```
def myraise(arg):
    try:
        if arg:
            raise ValueError('arg is True')
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
    else:
        print('arg is False')
    finally:
        print("see this no matter what")

myraise(1)
myraise(0)
```

You need to factor the unconditional code into `finally` and put the other stuff in `except`/`else` as appropriate.

Comment: But look at the last section of the python tutorial:
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions

Comment: @user1008636 -- That's just the tutorial.  It's written to make it explicit that an exception was raised in `try` and to demonstrate what happens in `except` or `finally` when there is an exception raised.  It is not meant to be an example of good usage for `try`/`except`.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are doing is "unPythonic". Trys should really only cover the small part (ideally one line) of the code which you expect might sometimes fail in a certain way. You should be able to use try/except/else/finally to get the required behaviour:

```
try:
    #line which might fail
except ExceptionType: # the exception type which you are worried about
    #what to do if it raises the exception
else:
    #this gets done if try is successful
finally:
    #this gets done last in both cases (try successful or not)
```